# localization of web.sitemap using a resx file in other project

Tags: localization, web.sitemap

I'm developing a web application and i'm using culture info localization.
All the localization resources of my application are in another project containing only resource (resx) files. This architecture is used because I have other applications using the same resources.

My problem now is the localization of web.sitemap. Currently I have a resx file to web.sitemap in the project and I reference it using the following syntax

title='$Resources:SiteMapRes,CLIPS_LIST'
description='$Resources:SiteMapRes,CLIPS_LIST

The problem is that this approach didn't work when I use resources contained in other projects.

Does any one know how to solve my problem?

Best regards,

José

Answer (score 1):

The sitemap uses the default localization provider to invoke the localization expression contained in the sitemapnode. The default provider doesn't allow for an external assembly to be set via the expression.
The only way to alter this behavior is to create your own localization provider. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) article shows how to do this. After setting up your own provider you can use an expression like this to access a resource from an external assembly:

The actual implementation of the provider is not very difficult as you will see in the article.

Regards,
Robin

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take would be to switch to external DI and then implement a custom IStringLocalizer class that can read the resources from another assembly. Here is a working example. I have created a [demo application](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_ExternalResources) on GitHub as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Resources;

namespace MvcSiteMapProvider.Globalization
{
    public class ResourceManagerStringLocalizer
        : IStringLocalizer
    {
        public ResourceManagerStringLocalizer(
            ResourceManager resourceManager
            )
        {
            if (resourceManager == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("resourceManager");
            this.resourceManager = resourceManager;
        }
        protected readonly ResourceManager resourceManager;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the localized text for the supplied attributeName.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="attributeName">The name of the attribute (as if it were in the original XML file).</param>
        /// <param name="value">The current object's value of the attribute.</param>
        /// <param name="enableLocalization">True if localization has been enabled, otherwise false.</param>
        /// <param name="classKey">The resource key from the ISiteMap class.</param>
        /// <param name="implicitResourceKey">The implicit resource key.</param>
        /// <param name="explicitResourceKeys">A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection"/> containing the explicit resource keys.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual string GetResourceString(string attributeName, string value, bool enableLocalization, string classKey, string implicitResourceKey, NameValueCollection explicitResourceKeys)
        {
            if (attributeName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("attributeName");
            }

            if (enableLocalization)
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                if (explicitResourceKeys != null)
                {
                    string[] values = explicitResourceKeys.GetValues(attributeName);
                    if ((values == null) || (values.Length <= 1))
                    {
                        result = value;
                    }
                    else if (this.resourceManager.BaseName.Equals(values[0]))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = this.resourceManager.GetString(values[1]);
                        }
                        catch (MissingManifestResourceException)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            {
                                result = value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can inject it into your DI configuration module (StructureMap example shown, but any DI container will do).

First of all, you need to specify not to register the IStringLocalizer interface automatically by adding it to the excludeTypes variable.

```
var excludeTypes = new Type[] {
// Use this array to add types you wish to explicitly exclude from convention-based  
// auto-registration. By default all types that either match I[TypeName] = [TypeName] or 
// I[TypeName] = [TypeName]Adapter will be automatically wired up as long as they don't 
// have the [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute].
//
// If you want to override a type that follows the convention, you should add the name 
// of either the implementation name or the interface that it inherits to this list and 
// add your manual registration code below. This will prevent duplicate registrations 
// of the types from occurring. 

// Example:
// typeof(SiteMap),
// typeof(SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy)
    typeof(IStringLocalizer)
};
```

Then provide an explicit registration of the ResourceManagerStringLocalizer (and its dependencies) instead.

```
// Configure localization

// Fully qualified namespace.resourcefile (.resx) name without the extension
string resourceBaseName = "SomeAssembly.Resources.Resource1";

// A reference to the assembly where your resources reside.
Assembly resourceAssembly = typeof(SomeAssembly.Class1).Assembly;

// Register the ResourceManager (note that this is application wide - if you are 
// using ResourceManager in your DI setup already you may need to use a named 
// instance or SmartInstance to specify a specific object to inject)
this.For<ResourceManager>().Use(() => new ResourceManager(resourceBaseName, resourceAssembly));

// Register the ResourceManagerStringLocalizer (uses the ResourceManger)
this.For<IStringLocalizer>().Use<ResourceManagerStringLocalizer>();
```

Then it is just a matter of specifying the resources appropriately. You need to start them with the Base Name (in this case `SomeAssembly.Resources.Resource1`), and then specify the key of the resource as the second argument.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:SomeAssembly.Resources.Resource1,ContactTitle" controller="Home" action="Contact"/>
```

Note that getting the BaseName right is the key to making it work. See the following MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5(v=vs.110).aspx